# Problema em exibir pontuação

Tags: android-studio

Olá!
Bom, criei um aplicativo quiz com 5 perguntas, tendo essas, 5 respostas certas. Minha intenção é mostrar na tela quantas respostas o usuário acertou e quantas ele errou, porém não conheço uma forma correta de computar esses dados sem usar mil if else.
Um arquivo XML - da activity questionario - tem todas as perguntas com respostas e um botão pra outra activity de resultados, e é lá onde estão os ids.

quero mostrar na activity do resultado algo semelhante a isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da activity resultado

```
public class ResultadoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado);

    /*VALOR NOME DA EDITTEXT*/
    EditText nome = findViewById(R.id.username);

    /*PEGAR SOMENTE OS IDS DAS OPTIONS CERTAS*/
    RadioButton a = findViewById(R.id.resp2);
    RadioButton b = findViewById(R.id.resp4);
    RadioButton c = findViewById(R.id.resp8);
    RadioButton d = findViewById(R.id.resp10);
    RadioButton e = findViewById(R.id.resp13);


public void callQuestao1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não deu pra entender bem o que você tá tentando fazer, mas o findViewById não é pra você procurar a resposta correta, é pra você relacionar com a view que foi criada, por exemplo, um editText, um button, um radio button, etc... Um exemplo:

```
Button botaoVerdadeiro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVerdadeiro);
Button botaoFalso = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFalso);
```

Você deveria guardar as respostas em alguma variável, uma variável pra guardar a opção que o usuário selecionou, uma pra acumular os acertos e então criar um método pra executar ao clicar no botão:

```
botaoVerdadeiro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    opcao = "verdadeiro";
                    if(opcao.equals(resposta)){
                        totalAcertos++;
}
```

Poderia também criar um botão de Finalizar e enviar os dados pela Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Resultado.class);

intent.putExtra(TOTAL_ACERTOS, totalAcertos);                        

startActivity(intent);
```

Na activity de Resultado você teria que fazer algo como isso:

```
Intent intentResultado = getIntent();
int totalAcertos = intentResultado.getIntExtra(MainActivity.TOTAL_ACERTOS, 0);

TextView acertos = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAcertos);
acertos.setText(resultadoAcertos);
```